# Apply function to each row of array with shape (28000,2304)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have an array of shape (28000, 2304). The following code is what I would like applied to each row and then a final array would be returned with size (28000, 5625)

```
image_array = X_train[0]
img = image_array.reshape(48,48)
resized_width = 75
resized_height = 75
dimension = (resized_width, resized_height)

resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
image_array = resized.flatten()
```

X_train is my array of shape (28000, 2304). X_train[0] would be the first row in the array of 28000. The above code returns a vector of length (5625) after flattening the resized image array. So I would like to apply the above code to all 28000 rows not just X_train[0]. How would I go about iterating or looping through X_train and apply this code to have a final array of shape (28000, 5625). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a simple for loop across all rows, appending the values to a result array will yield you 28000 rows with each row containing your `image_array` element

```
result = []
for image_row in X_train:
    image_array = image_row
    img = image_array.reshape(48,48)
    resized_width = 75
    resized_height = 75
    dimension = (resized_width, resized_height)

    resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    image_array = resized.flatten()
    result.append(image_array)
```

Comment: Thanks much that helped greatly. Next I needed to convert each from 1 channel (75,75,1) to 3 channel (75,75,3). This was accomplished using skimage.color

Answer (score 0):

THIS DID THE TRICK...

```
from skimage.color import grey2rgb
resized_width = 75
resized_height = 75

X_train_resized = []
for image_row in X_train:
    image_array = image_row
    img = image_array.reshape(48,48)
    dimension = (resized_width, resized_height)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = resized
    rgb_img = grey2rgb(img)
    rgb_img = rgb_img.astype('uint8')
    X_train_resized.append(rgb_img)

X_test_resized = []
for image_row in X_test:
    image_array = image_row
    img = image_array.reshape(48,48)
    dimension = (resized_width, resized_height)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = resized
    rgb_img = grey2rgb(img)
    rgb_img = rgb_img.astype('uint8')
    X_test_resized.append(rgb_img)
```